# appending new data to specific elements in lists in r

Tags: r, list, append, rbind

Please correct me if my terminology is wrong because on this question Im not quite sure what Im dealing with regarding elements, objects, lists..I just know its not a data frame.
Using the example from `prepksel {adehabitatHS}` I am trying to modify my own data to fit into their package.  Running this command on their example data creates an object? called x which is a list with 3 sections? elements? to it.
The example data code:

```
 library(adehabitatHS)
    data(puechabonsp)
    locs <- puechabonsp$relocs
    map <- puechabonsp$map
    pc <- mcp(locs[,"Name"])
    hr <- hr.rast(pc, map)
    cp <- count.points(locs[,"Name"], map)
     x <- prepksel(map, hr, cp)
```

looking at the structure of x it is a list of 3 elements called tab, weight, and factor

```
str(x) 
List of 3
 $ tab   :'data.frame': 191 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ Elevation : num [1:191] 141 140 170 160 152 121 104 102 106 103 ...
  ..$ Aspect    : num [1:191] 4 4 4 1 1 1 1 1 4 4 ...
  ..$ Slope     : num [1:191] 20.9 18 17 24 23.9 ...
  ..$ Herbaceous: num [1:191] 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 ...
 $ weight: num [1:191] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 4 0 1 ...
 $ factor: Factor w/ 4 levels "Brock","Calou",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

for my data, I will create multiple `"x"` lists and want to merge the data within each segment.  So, I have created an `"x"` for year 2007, 2008 and 2009.  Now, I want to append the `"tab"` element of 08 to 07, then 09 to 07/08. and do the same for the `"weight"` and `"factor"` elements of this list `"x"`.  How do you bind that data?  I thought about using `unlist` on each segment of the list and then appending and then joining the yearly data for each segment and then rejoining the three segments back into one list.  But this was cumbersome and seemed rather inefficient.

I know this is not how it will work, but in my head this is what I should be doing:

```
newlist<-append(x07$tab, x08$tab, x09$tab)
newlist<-append(x07$weight, x08$weight, x09$weight)
newlist<-append(x07$factor, x08$factor, x09$factor)
```

maybe `rbind`? `do.call("rbind", lapply(....uh...stuck`

Comment: "What I will create multiple x lists and want to append each element within the list to make 1 list." Huh?

Comment: Thanks for giving `str(x)`. `dput(x)` would be really useful as well.

Comment: @BlueMagister I didn't put dput(x) because the first part of the code I provide anyone can run simply copy and paste to go.  I thought it would avoid creating a long message, because my concern is more with how to join new data to different sections within a list.

Comment: @joran apologies that What shouldn't have been there.  I also reworded and tried to make what I was talking about more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append` works for vectors and lists, but won't give the output you want for data frames, the elements in your list (and they are lists) are of different types. Something like

```
tocomb <- list(x07,x08,x09)
newlist <- list(
  tab = do.call("rbind",lapply(tocomb,function(x) x$tab)), 
  weight = c(lapply(tocomb,function(x) x$weight),recursive=TRUE), 
  factor = c(lapply(tocomb,function(x) x$factor),recursive=TRUE)
)
```

You may need to be careful with factors if they have different levels - something like `as.character` on the factors before converting them back with `as.factor`.

This isn't tested, so some assembly may be required. I'm not an R wizard, and this may not be the best answer.

Comment: some assembly is required :)  I get an Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : names do not match previous names.  I think this is because there is one variable within the 'tab' segment that is named map07 or map08. So I have to rename that variable and then your function should work.  What does 'recursive' do and why is it not used after "x$tab" when it is used after $weight or $factor?  is that part of the 'lapply' or the 'do.call'?

Comment: You will need to make sure the names of the data frame columns are all the same, so instead of `function(x) x$tab`, do something like `function(x) {y <- x$tab; names(y) <- tab.names; return(y)}` where `tab.names` is a vector of names. `recursive=TRUE` tells `c` to combine things within the lists returned by `lapply`; see `?c` for more details. Because `weight` and `factor` are vectors, they can be combined with `c`. As `tab` is a data frame, a different process is required for combination. See `?do.call` for details.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation regarding recursive and c.  It helps clarify some of the readings. I followed the advise of using `as.character` and `as. factor`.  But Im losing the names.  my new  line says `factor=as.factor(as.character(c(lapply(wprep,function(x) x$factor),recursive=TRUE)))` and it is turning all the levels into "numbers" instead of keeping the character names I had assigned. Sorry for calling it factor, that is what was used in the example `adehabitatHS`

Comment: You want to convert to character before you combine with `c`. Try: `factor=as.factor(c(lapply(wprep,function(x) as.character(x$factor)),recursive=TRUE))`